# In Rails 4, how can I change the text in the nav bar based on the current page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, partial

I am working on a Rails 4 project where I would like a different link to appear on the navigation bar depending on the current page. This is how I am trying to set it up:

```
<ul>
  <% if current_page?("/company") %>
    <li>Company Space</li>
  <% elsif current_page?("/user_page") %>
    <li>User Space</li>
  <% else %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I know I've written this part correctly, because when I put it in the `application.html.erb` layout page, it works just fine. When I put the same exact thing in the top nav bar, however, it doesn't work. The nav bar is in a partial called `_header.html.erb` which is currently rendered in the layout as follows:

```
<body>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

  <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
  <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
  <%= yield %>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</body>
```

I assume this has something to do with the nav bar not detecting the current page. I am hoping someone can tell me why this is happening, and ideally I would like to find a relatively DRY solution that would allow me to have this feature. (I have thought of creating separate partials for the different conditions, and then putting the logic for displaying the partial in `application.html.erb`, but given that this is far from the only content in the nav bar, the maintainability of that seems quite dismal.)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: in your view files you can use `controller_name` and `action_name` methods which returns name of the current page controller or action.

Comment: how many 'dependings' are there?  is there a list of pages that all get `/company` and a list that get `/user` - or many pages all with different conditions?

Comment: @dax, there are only these two particular static pages that I'm trying to control with these conditions. Once the user has signed in, I am controlling the appearance of the nav bar depending on attributes of the `current_user`, which is working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand upon nathan's answer, specify action

```
<% if params[:action] == 'company' %>
    <li>Company Space</li>
<% else params[:action] == 'user_page' %>
    <li>User Space</li>
<% end %>
```

This will work... but it doesn't feel like the cleanest way. Perhaps go about doing it with JS for it to be cleaner?

Comment: besides answering my question, thank you for noting that JS might be cleaner. I was not thinking about that option, but I will keep it in mind now.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% if params[:controller] == 'company' %>
    <li>Company Space</li>
<% else params[:controller] == 'user_page' %>
    <li>User Space</li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Company and user_page are both static pages, and their controller is `static_pages_controller.rb`. When I put this code in the nav bar, it is always displaying the text "User Space" because the condition in the first line is never met.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it more cleaner by moving the following to respected helper file.

```
  def nav_bar_content(action)
     if action == 'company'
      "Company Space"
     elsif action == 'user_page'
      "User Space"
     else
       # statement
     end
  end
```

and call `<li><%= nav_bar_content(params[:action]) %></li>` this is on your nav bar